# Detect barcode by Tibar titanium

Tags: titanium, barcode, titanium-mobile, barcode-scanner

I have done steps as this link for detect barcode in Iphone in Titanium.
http://code.google.com/p/tibar/
In line config, I done as that link but it only display Album in Iphone.
I have configured again as follow:

```
configure: {
        classType: "ZBarReaderController",
        sourceType: "Camera",
        cameraMode: "Default",
        symbol:{
            "QR-Code":true,
        }
    }
```

It displayed screen to detect barcode with camera.But when click scan button ,camera can't detect barcode.Images barcode that scaned is very clear. 
If you done that work,can you help me..Thank

Comment: Well...are you trying to scan a QR-Code?

Comment: I want to use it to scan barcode(ISBN) in books..:)

Comment: Then you should enable EAN13/ISBN13/ISBN8 and not QR-Code... ... ... ... ... ...

Answer (score 1):

You set QR-code to true, should of course not be that:

```
configure: {
        classType: "ZBarReaderController",
        sourceType: "Camera",
        cameraMode: "Default",
        symbol:{
            "EAN-13":true
        }
}
```

Taken directly from the documentation you provided us.